# javascript: Get value by clicking on current value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building datatables and by setting up total records in database I have total count of them.

Now I am little confused about click event in JavaScript.
This is how i am doing this:

```
 for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
                $("#newList").append('<li id="pageno" value=""' + cnt + ' onclick="GetPageno();" > ' + cnt + '</li>');
            }
```

This is my current loop that will set 5 numbers of list. Now if I want to get value of current list then I am doing this:

```
function GetPageno() {
        //this.val();


        alert(document.getElementById('pageno').val());


    }
```

I have 1 to 5 numbers list on web page.

How do I get value of that number I clicked?

Ex. If I clicked "5", then alert should be coming with value "5", same as for all the list elements.

Comment: `$(this).val()` inside `GetPageno` should do it.

Comment: `li` shouldn't have value attributes, ids should be unique, you shouldn't use inline javascript, val() a jQuery method ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `<li id="pageno"` this you are repeating same id more than once and thats not correct.

Instead use `<li id="pageno_'+cnt+'"` and use below code.

```
$(document).on('click','li[id^="pageno_"]',function(){
   alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

#### [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/rb8Hm/2/)

Comment: heheh I'll suggest on Meta to add a bonus to everyone - to have  monthly one possiblity to view who downvoted ;) (joke)

Comment: @Manoz It's just [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: @Manoz +1 for find out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `val()` on `li` which is not correct, you can use .attr("value") it would be better if you use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes e.g data-someattributeName to make it more clear. You are assigning same id to more then one elements which is not legal. Assign a class to them and bind event with class and you will be able to get the required attribute.

*Add class to li element when you create them, you are not assigning `cnt` to `value` properly and assigning empty string to value*

```
for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
     $("#newList").append('<li id="pageno" class="pageno" value=""' + cnt + ' onclick="GetPageno();" > ' + cnt + '</li>');
}
```

*Bind click event using [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)*

```
$(".pageno").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
})
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aKMHD/)**, using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and class selector. Here I have also assigned **unique** `Ids` to `pageno`.

```
pageno = 1;
for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
     $("#newList").append('<li id="pageno"'+cnt+' class="pageno" data-custom="' + cnt + '" onclick="GetPageno();" > ' + cnt + '</li>');
}

$(".pageno").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('custom'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**id's must be unique**, you could do:

```
for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
   $("#newList").append('<li class="pageno" value="'+cnt+'"> ' + cnt + '</li>');
}
```

and:

```
$("#newList").on("click", "li.pageno", function() {
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

jsFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfAbn/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake in your value attribute. The double quote to be moved just after the cnt.
And Pass the li object to the function i.e, GetPageno(this) as follows,

```
 for (var cnt = 1; cnt <= 5; cnt++) {
     $("#newList").append('<li id="pageno" value="' + cnt + '" onclick="GetPageno(this);" > ' + cnt + '</li>');
 }
```

Then get the value of the li object passed in the method.

```
function GetPageno(obj) {
    alert(obj.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique, you should use class instead. Then you can use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over your class:

```
$(".pageno").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having an issue because of the following:

- `id`s need to be unique, you should be using a `class`.
- You should also attach your event afterwards, not inline (preference).
- Refer to your element as `this` and use `.text()` not `.val()` as `value` isn't a valid attribute on a `li`.

  ```
  for (var cnt = 1; cnt < 5; cnt++) {
      $("#newList").append('<li class="pageno" ' + cnt + '>' + cnt + '</li>');
  }
  $('.pageno').click(GetPageno);

  function GetPageno() {
      alert($(this).text());
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
                    $("#newList").append('<li id="pageno"+cnt value=""' + cnt + ' onclick="GetPageno(this.value);" > ' + cnt + '</li>');
                }
    function GetPageno(val) {


            alert(val);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use class name for all

instead of id. id must be unique in whole html page

you can change you code like

```
for (var cnt = pageno; cnt < pageno + 5; cnt++) {
 $("#newList").append('<li class="pageno" value="'+cnt+'"> ' + cnt + '</li>');
}
```

and add new jquery function in document ready scope

```
$(".pageno").click(function() {
alert($(this).attr('value'));
```

})